# Base64 To ImageIO

Tags: java, image, jsp, base64, javax.imageio

I'm trying to convert a base64 string to an `imageIO` and saving it.

In a bigger context, I'm creating a script so users can upload an image, crop it and save it as their profile image. I get a `Base64` String from this cropped image, and sent it to the servlet. (Yes, I'm using Java Server Pages)

Here is the problem:
When i execute the following code, i get a null pointer on my variable Image in the method `decodeToImage`.

I tried to use several other libraries to decode the base64 but with no results yet.
I tried to use other image convert scripts but none worked.

Also this code seems to me that is should work. Am i missing something?

Thanks in advance!

All reactions are welcome!

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);

    if(request.getParameter("upload-CroppedImage") != null){


        BufferedImage newImage = decodeToImage(request.getParameter("croppedImage"));

        File outputfile = new File("F:\\Users\\Joery v2\\Pictures\\saved.jpg");
        ImageIO.write(newImage, "jpg", outputfile);
    }
}

public static BufferedImage decodeToImage(String imageString) {

    try {
        byte[] imgBytes = parseBase64Binary(imageString);
         BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imgBytes));
         return image;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

*This is code from the servlet.

Stack Trace:

```
Info:   GameZ_Website was successfully deployed in 2.076 milliseconds.
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[CroppingImage]: Servlet.service() for servlet CroppingImage threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromRenderedImage(ImageTypeSpecifier.java:925)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.getWriter(ImageIO.java:1592)
```

Comment: It's not "serverlet" it's `servlet`. Also, the stacktrace will tell you what's null, so show the (beginning of the) stacktrace.

Comment: as @Kayaman said the stack trace will tell you what's null. Add it to your post.

Comment: Added the stack trace, sorry for the servlet typo.

Comment: Can you post an example Base64 string (first 20 chars or so), *as received by the servlet*? Perhaps you are using data URI's, and forgot to strip away the scheme/mime-type etc before the actual Base64 string? What format is the encoded image supposed to have? PS: Unless you intend to modify the image in the servlet, there really is no need to use ImageIO. Instead, just write the decoded Base64 bytes directly to your output file (it's faster and more compatible).

Comment: data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAARgAAAEYCAYAAACHjumMAA this is example of the base64 i send to the servlet. Do i need to strip away the data:image/png?

Comment: @JoeryVreijsen Yes. This is not Base64, it is a [Data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). You need to strip everything until (and including) the comma after "base64".

Comment: @haraldK Thank you very much! Going to try that right away. Will let you know if it worked. Thanks again.

Comment: @haraldK I stripped away the first 21 characters of the string, and it worked. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code, to avoid the decode/encode cycle, and see if your image looks as expected:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);

    if (request.getParameter("upload-CroppedImage") != null) {
        String dataURI = request.getParameter("croppedImage");
        String data = dataURI.substring(dataURI.indexOf(',')); // TODO: Input validation
        byte[] imgBytes = parseBase64Binary(data);

        File outputfile = new File("F:\\Users\\Joery v2\\Pictures\\saved.jpg");
        writeBytesToFile(imgBytes, outputFile);
    }
}

private void writeBtesToFile(byte[] bytes, File file) {
    OutputStream out;

    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        out.write(bytes);
    } 
    finally {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It did remove any errors from the code, but the image that is saved, is an image that i can't open. It says it's an invalid image.

Comment: Ok, so what does the `croppedImage` parameter contain? What does the Base64 encoded string contain (example please)? Pretty much the only things that can go wrong now that we got rid of ImageIO, is a) the input is incorrect (i.e not an image), b) the input is incorrectly encoded (ie. not Base64), c) the input is incorrectly parsed (ie, there's something wrong with `parseBase64Binary`).

Comment: That is what i think, so this is a sample input of de base64: data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAARgA. Do i have to strip away the data:image/png?

Comment: See comment to your question.